# Can't see the extension I've installed in GeneXus 15

Tags: genexus, workwithplus

I've installed the SmartDevicePlus (from DVelop) extension in my Genexus15 folder. The setup ends telling me it completed successfully. Yet, I can't find the SD+ menu in Tools.

I've also tried to install the WorkWithPlus (from DVelop) extension from the Add-in manager but here is the message I got:
1)File DVelopWorkWithPlus_9.1.15_Ev2_U4_higher_Setup.rar installed correctly.
2)Failed to install file DVelopWorkWithPlus_9.1.15_Ev2_U4_higher_Setup.rar.

Comment: Can you check that the SD+ extension is listed in the Tools -> Extension Manager dialog? You should see the extension listed over there, with a checkbox next to it that controls whether the extension is loaded or not. I'm guessing the checkbox will be unchecked in your case. If the checkbox is disabled, that means the extension could not be loaded for some reason. Hovering over the checkbox should show a tooltip message with the reason.

Answer (score 4):

You should install the proper setups for Gx 15 for both WorkWithPlus and SmartDevicesPlus, you can download them from www.dvelop.com.uy/downloads.

By using this setups you should use the products on Gx15. If you have other problems please write us to support@workwithplus.com or by Skype (supportwwp) so we can connect by Team Viewer and help you with the first steps.

We can also schedule an online demo of the products so you can take further advantage of your tests with them!

Sofía